# Calculate $\int_{-\infty}^\infty x^2e^{-x^2} dx$ using Gaussian random variables and the properties of pdfs

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, gaussian-integral

I've been asked the following question in an exam of probability and statistics undergraduate course. Help is appreciated.

**Calculate the numeric value of $\int_{-\infty}^\infty x^2e^{-x^2} dx$ using Gaussian random variables and the properties of pdfs (probability density functions).**

*Note: The normal cdf table was given*

Here is how I tried to solve it:

- Take the normal pdf and use the fact that pdfs are equal to 1 when integrated from $-\infty$ to $\infty$.

$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{\sigma \sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}} dx = 1$

- Let $\mu = 0$ and $\sigma^2 = \frac{1}{2}$. And the integral simplifies to this.

$\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2} dx = \sqrt{\pi}$

- Then I've tried to integrate the main integral by parts.

$\int x^2e^{-x^2} dx = x^2 \int e^{-x^2} dx - \int2x(\int e^{-x^2} dx) dx $

- Plug in $\sqrt{\pi}$ where needed and simplify.

$= x^2 \sqrt{\pi}  - \int 2x( \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2} erf(x) ) dx $

- Further simplifying I get the following and this is where I stuck.

$= x^2 \sqrt{\pi}  - \sqrt{\pi} \int x \, erf(x) dx $

- The functions don't converge, so I can't proceed. Also, I don't know how to integrate the error function.

If you know how to proceed, or if you think this should've been solved in another way, please answer. Note that I need a solution involving Gaussian random variables and the properties of pdfs (as required.)

Comment: Take the substitution $x = \frac {y} {\sqrt 2}.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The step where you "plug in $\sqrt{\pi}$ as needed" is incorrect. On the preceding line you have *indefinite* integrals, where you haven't kept track of the bounds of integration. Turning it into definite integrals would also affect the factor $x^2$, for example.

Also, it's much better to do the integration by parts like this, and not involve the error function:
$$
\int_a^b (x e^{-x^2}) \cdot x \, dx = \Bigl[(-\tfrac12 e^{-x^2} ) \cdot x \Bigr]_a^b - \int_a^b (-\tfrac12 e^{-x^2} ) \cdot 1 \, dx
,
$$
and then see what happens as $a \to -\infty$ and $b \to \infty$.

(I know this isn't a probabilistic solution, but it's just to comment on your attempt.)

Comment: How did you integrate the left part here?

Comment: @DenizBasgoren: Well, what is the derivative of $-\tfrac12 e^{-x^2}$? I'm just using the chain rule backwards.

Answer (score 0):

You probably know $\mu,\,\sigma^2$ are the variable's mean and variance. If its pdf is $$f(x):=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\exp-x^2,$$then by definition $\int_{\Bbb R}xf(x)dx$ is the mean $\mu$ and $\int_{\Bbb R}x^2f(x)dx$ is $$E(X^2)=(E(X))^2+\operatorname{Var}X=\mu^2+\sigma^2.$$In other words, $$\int_{\Bbb R}\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}x^2\exp-x^2dx=0^2+\tfrac12=\tfrac12$$so $\int_{\Bbb R}x^2\exp-x^2dx=\tfrac12\sqrt{\pi}$.

Comment: Could you elaborate this please, I can't follow you

Comment: @DenizBasgoren Sure; see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

The integral corresponds to the variance of a Gaussian variable with average $0$ and standard deviation $\dfrac1{\sqrt2}$, to the normalization coefficient, $\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma$.

Hence

$$\frac I{\sqrt\pi}=\dfrac12.$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Note that$$Var(X){=\int x^2f_X(x)dx\\=\int x^2\cdot {1\over \sqrt \pi}e^{-x^2}dx\\={1\over 2}}$$